# Error in MySQL syntax: What am i missing?

Tags: php, sql-insert

I get this error when try to execute the code below:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near **'desc,dir,pais,tel,fax,email,url,pic) VALUES ('lucent','que lio','sadsad','dsadsa' at line 1**

```
<?php 
    include('config.php');
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $usuario = $login_session;
        $name = $_POST['empname'];
        $desc = $_POST['empdesc'];
        $dir = $_POST['empdir'];
        $pais = $_POST['empais'];
        $tel = $_POST['emptel'];
        $fax = $_POST['empfax'];
        $email = $_POST['empemail'];
        $url = $_POST['empurl'];
        $pic = 'nopic.png';

        $success = "INSERT INTO empresas
                (usuario,name,desc,dir,pais,tel,fax,email,url,pic) 
            VALUES('$usuario','$name','$desc','$dir','$pais',
                '$tel','$fax','$email','$url','$pic')";

        $data = mysql_query ($success)or die(mysql_error());

    }
```

Comment: You're missing proper escaping, for example. Or prepared statements. Or a non-deprecated mysql api.

Comment: `desc` is a keyword, if you want to use it as a column name, you need to enclose it in backticks. See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993465/selecting-a-column-that-is-also-a-keyword-in-mysql

Comment: echo the contents of $success out so you can see what mysql is being told to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any time you see this:

```
... for the right syntax to use near...
```

The error is at the very beginning of what "near" is telling you.  In this case it's the word `desc` which is a reserved word in SQL (for ordering things in descending order).  I recommend *not* using it as a column name (or any other reserved word), but if that's not possible then you'll just need to wrap it in back-ticks to indicate that it's an object name and not a keyword:

```
INSERT INTO empresas(usuario,name,`desc`,dir,pais,tel,fax,email,url,pic)...
```

It's often a good idea to wrap object names like this anyway, making queries more explicit.  Though honestly you should take this a step further and use something like PDO for building your queries.  At the very least, please be aware that your current code is ***highly vulnerable*** to SQL injection attacks and start reading [this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error you're experiencing is because `desc` is a [MySQL reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html).

If you want to use it as a field name, you'll need to quote it;

```
INSERT INTO empresas(usuario, name, `desc`, dir, pais, tel, fax, email, url, pic) VALUES ...
```

You should also strongly consider not using the deprecated `mysql_*` API, the newer APIs like PDO or MySQLi give you access to prepared statements which will prevent [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) which your code has problems with.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "desc" as a colum name since it's already in MYSQL's use

Comment: Thank you guys, DESC was the problem. Can u add what names i cant use as a Column, besides DESC?

Comment: You can't use functions and keywords. You should check them in http://www.mysql.com

Answer (score 0):

Your column name 'desc' is the mysql's reserved word, Check this [Mysql Reserved Words](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html)

Answer (score 0):

Put backticks for the desc column as follows

```
$success = "INSERT INTO empresas(usuario,name,`desc`,dir,pais,tel,fax,email,url,pic) VALUES ('$usuario','$name','$desc','$dir','$pais','$tel','$fax','$email','$url','$pic')";
```

or maybe just use another column name