# Good Syntax Getting Syntax Error #1064 from PHPMyAdmin

Tags: mysql

I am getting this error:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax....near 'Group) 
VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', '$group')' at line 1
```

With this code:

```
INSERT INTO T2T_Main.users (Username, Password, EmailAddress, Group) 
VALUES ('$username', '$password', '$email', '$group')
```

But I cannot figure out what the problem is. It looks fine to me!

Comment: Is it because "group" is a reserved keyword?

Comment: Try backticks or double quotes

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selecting a column that is also a keyword in MySQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993465/selecting-a-column-that-is-also-a-keyword-in-mysql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Change column name **Group** because it is a function or key word used in  mysql syntax.

Comment: It is a "reserved word", but close enough