# Sql syntax error caused by reserved names

Tags: mysql

i have an syntax error in my sql 
it has to do with the use of reserved names(user security). i cant seem to figure out how to put the quotes can someone please help me fix this.

```
ALTER TABLE `user` ADD FOREIGN KEY `security_check_id` REFERENCES `security_check`(security_check_id)
```

**#1064 - Er is iets fout in de gebruikte syntax bij 'REFERENCES `security_check`(security_check_id)' in regel 1**

Translated sorry for the bad translation

**#1064 - There is an mistake in the used syntax at 'REFERENCES `security_check`(security_check_id)' at line 1**

Comment: The obvious solution would be to avoid using reserved names for any of your own objects. Then there's never any confusion. I'm sure you can think of a slightly different name fairly easily.

Comment: P.S. Is this MySQL, or something else? The way you add quotes etc is different between different database engines. Please add the relevant tag.

Comment: for use reserve names in sqlserver you can use [] .ex:[security]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pease check this answer, it might be helpful -

[Selecting a column that is also a keyword in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3993465/selecting-a-column-that-is-also-a-keyword-in-mysql)

In your case try -

```sql
ALTER TABLE `user` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`security_id`) REFERENCES `security`(`security_id`)
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=946f293a4e54911ae0fb7b972f4442b3 - can you make a working one? The documentation for REFERENCES in MySQL shows specifically the brackets must be used, anyway. Plus we don't know 100% for certain that this is definitely MySQL, although it seems likely.

Comment: sorry it is my sql

Comment: @james in that case please edit your question to show that (you can add a tag, and update the description). Also, it would help a lot if you tell us the exact error message you are seeing.

Comment: hey @james, you were missing ADD. I have updated the SQL and it's working. Try with the updated query!

Answer (score 1):

ADD FOREIGN KEY `security_check_id` is incorrect if `security_check_id` is a column you wish to reference then it must be enclosed in parenthesis ie ADD FOREIGN KEY (`security_check_id`) if `security_check_id` is a name you intend to give the FK then it should be followed by the column in parenthesis that you wish to check..

BTW none of the column or table names are reserved words so they don't need to be escaped